# SLSQP optimizer(scipy.minimize) doesn't update parameters

Tags: programming, optimization, pennylane

I'm trying to find optimal parameters that minimize the cost functions.
In cost function, it calculates the classical-fisher-information at a certain point(phi[0] = np.pi).

Cost-function takes 3-parameters(= theta_init, tau_1, tau_2). With those three parameters, it calculates the circuit_2. And circuit_2 has only one parameters(= phi) because the functions which calculate classical fisher information(CFI) should take only one parameters. That's the reason why I create two quantum circuit.

However, when I run the code, it doesn't work. For example, I set initial_parameters as 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 but, the result doesn't change. At least it should be updated with different values since cost-function is not minimum at given initial_parameters.

[image: It returns same parameters as initial values. It should be updated]

I guess problems may occur during the update of the global variable(= Paras_global) in the cost function. But when I put various parameters in the cost function, it always makes different results which means the global variable is appropriately works. Could this one be the reason for the problem?

Here is my code:

```
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np

import scipy as sp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 2-qubit
dev = qml.device('default.mixed', wires= 2)

# == Hamiltonian setup == 
coeffs = [1]
obs = [qml.PauliZ(0) @ qml.PauliZ(1)]

hamiltonian = qml.Hamiltonian(coeffs, obs)


# == Generate circuit == 

# global var
Paras_global = None

# Entnalger 
@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit_1(paras):
    theta_init, tau_1, tau_2 = paras
    
    # Stage_1: RY for pi/2
    qml.RY(np.pi/2, wires=0)
    qml.RY(np.pi/2, wires=1)
    
    # Stage_2: Entangler    
    qml.ApproxTimeEvolution(hamiltonian, tau_1, 1)
    qml.RX(theta_init, wires = 0)    
    qml.RX(theta_init, wires = 1)    

    qml.RY(-np.pi/2, wires = 0)    
    qml.RY(-np.pi/2, wires = 1)   

    qml.ApproxTimeEvolution(hamiltonian, tau_2, 1)

    qml.RY(np.pi/2, wires = 0)    
    qml.RY(np.pi/2, wires = 1) 
    
    return qml.density_matrix(wires=[0, 1])

@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit_2(phi):
    global Paras_global
    density_matrix = circuit_1(Paras_global)
    qml.QubitDensityMatrix(density_matrix, wires=[0, 1])
    
    # Stage_3: Accumulate
    qml.ApproxTimeEvolution(hamiltonian, phi, 1)
    qml.RX(np.pi/2, wires=0)
    qml.RX(np.pi/2, wires=1)
    
    return qml.density_matrix(wires=[0, 1])


# == Cost_function #1 ==
def Cost_function(paras):
    global Paras_global
    # expect: theta_init, tau_1, tau_2 = paras
    Paras_global = paras
    
    phi = np.array([np.pi])
    # phi = np.pi
    # circuit_2(phi[0])
    
    CFI = qml.qinfo.classical_fisher(circuit_2)(phi[0])
    return CFI


initial_guess = 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
sp.optimize.minimize(Cost_function, initial_guess, method='SLSQP')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it expected that your cost function is almost constant to $0$? Changing the parameters change the result by approximately $10^{-31}$

Comment: Infact the goal is to maximize the cost functions. But I set the return value without minus for some test.

Comment: Even if you want to maximize it, is it expected that the classical fisher information for this matrix, whatever the parameters you use, is around $10^{-31}$? Or can you provide a set of parameters such that this quantity is larger?

Comment: Because with such small numbers, inaccuracies can happen, which may mess with the optimizer, or maybe the optimizer is set to stop if it sees no progress larger than $10^{-6}$

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe threshold was the problem. Thanks for your help